# Calculating difference between time now and scheduledstart crm c#

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

How can i calculate difference between the time now and the "scheduledstart" field (in appointment entity) and put the value into another number field ("el_early_cancel_notice" - like duration field).
This is what i wrote untill now but i don't know how to proceed. Can someone help?

```
      if ((serviceAppontment.Attributes.Contains("scheduledstart")) && (serviceAppontment.Attributes["scheduledstart"] != null) && (TimeNow > SchelStart))
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(serviceAppontment.Attributes["scheduledstart"].ToString());
                try
                {
                    //here i need to calculate the difference and i don't know where to begin...
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startDate = (DateTime)serviceAppontment["scheduledstart"];
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.UtcNow - startDate;

serviceAppointment["el_early_cancel_notice"] = diff.Days;
localContext.OrganizationService.Update(serviceAppoinment);
```

Because DateTime is stored in UTC format in CRM, you need to deal with DateTime in UTC. And I assume you want duration in days. More about TimeSpan [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

1) Cast your field to a date time:

DateTime startDate = (DateTime)serviceAppontment.Attributes["scheduledstart"];

2) Use one of [these methods](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/DateDiff_CS_DC09132006172429PM/DateDiff_CS_DC.aspx) to get a TimeSpan.

3) Update your el_early_cancel_notice field with information from the TimeSpan:
serviceAppontment.Attributes["el_early_cancel_notice"] = [Appropriate number from TimeSpan];

Comment: how can i applay this on crm fields?